# Is it ok to persist the Child entity along with the Parent entity when having a One-To-One JPA relationship in between them?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade, one-to-one

I am having two Entity classes, `Company` and `CompanyTypeAutomobile`.
These two have `One-To-One` relationships.

```
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name = "company_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer companyId;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 255, updatable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    private CompanyType companyType;

    //other fields

}

public class CompanyTypeAutomobile {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

}
```

`Company` contains the basic details of a company, and the other fields would be contained in its child entity(based on the type of Company)
Now, when If `Company` is created, should I create the `CompanyTypeAutomobile` also in the same process?

I am having a requirement where I am in such a situation. If for some company, it has only basic details in `Company` and other details were not created and I want GET the complete details of the company then the persistence layer would return me `EntityNotFoundException` for `CompanyTypeAutomobile`.

So I just want to create the child entity, only with the `id` field. Is it a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

> Now, when If Company is created, should I create the `CompanyTypeAutomobile` also in the same process?

It depends on whether the child entity is mandatory or not.

When you load the child entity using the `Company` identifier:

```
CompanyTypeAutomobile details = entityManager.find(CompanyTypeAutomobile.class, company.getId());
```

you will get `null` if there is no `CompanyTypeAutomobile` in the DB, not an `EntityNotFoundException`.

> So I just want to create the child entity, only with the id field. Is it a good practice?

No, it's not. That would be a hack.

If you get an `EntityNotFoundException`, it means you mapped the child association in the parent entity, which is [a mistake](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

In that case, remove the `CompanyTypeAutomobile` association in the parent `Company` entity as it will behave according to the [EAGER fetching strategy](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/) and lead to [N+1 query issues](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-detect-the-n-plus-one-query-problem-during-testing/).

Comment: I don't have `CompanyTypeAutomobile` association in the parent `Company` entity. I am using `Spring-data-jpa`, so it's up to me if I want to return null or some exception if the `CompanyTypeAutomobile` is not found. `CompanyTypeAutomobile companyTypeAutomobile = companyTypeAutomobileDao.findById(companyId).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("companyTypeOther not found"));`

Comment: This is handled by a controller method. I am confused, should I return the exception or a `CompanyTypeAutomobile` object with all of its field `null`

Comment: `CompanyTypeOther companyTypeOther = companyTypeOtherDao.findById(companyId).orElse(new CompanyTypeOther());`. This seems kind of a hack.